# Getting error while inserting image

Tags: errors

I am trying to insert a image which is in `.eps` format from my computer into latex file. But I always get an error if I add the scale part but works fine without scale.
Here is my code below.

Works fine:

```
    \begin{figure}
    \centering
    \includegraphics{Plot1}
    \caption{Sales vs Assets}
    \end{figure}
```

Doesn't work fine:

```
\begin{figure}
        \centering
        \includegraphics[scale=.8]{Plot1}
        \caption{Sales vs Assets}
        \end{figure}
```

Comment: What's the error?

Comment: Overfull \hbox..

Comment: Try to use `\fbox{\includegraphics{}}` to see the size of the bounding box of you picture. By the way, `\overfull` is not an error, but only a warning.

Comment: But the problem is my image is not coming completely in the pdf.How do I scale it?

Comment: Run away argument is one more err

Comment: I guess that is not a good idea to run `pdflatex`with `.eps` images. Try to run `latex` first.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are using:

```
\usepackage{graphics}
```

But you need:

```
\usepackage{graphicx}
```

that extends package `graphics` and changes the syntax of `\includegraphics` to support key value options in the optional argument.